# How to set default languages for a filetype extension in IPython/Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whenever an file with `.m` extension is opened using the Jupyter Notebook, it always uses Mathematica as the language for syntax highlighting. I would like to open in Octave language. This can be done by scrolling through the entire list of languages in the drop-down box, but I had to go this every time I open a file.

Is there a way to set the default language syntax for a given file extension in Jupyter Notebook?